# Ionic Tabs dissapears when redirecting

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In my project i have a tab-bar which contains out of 3 tabs. But when my project starts i want to redirect to a page that doesn't exist in the tab-bar and to see if the user is logedin and then redirect to one of the tabs again. 
At the page outside of the tabs i dont want to show the tabs (obviously) but then on all other pages i want the tabs to be shown. I have simplyfied my code so that its only the code needed.

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;

  constructor(public oneSignal: OneSignal, platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

      //this.nav.push(Test);
      //this.nav.setRoot(Test);
      this.rootPage = Test;

      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();



    });
  }
}
```

Here is my page which i redirects to:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'test.html'
})
export class Test {

    rootPage:any;
  constructor(private natCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
      this.rootPage = TabsPage;
      this.natCtrl.setRoot(ContactPage);
  }
}
```

[image]

As you can see the tabs isn't there.

I have tried many different ways to do this including push, setroot etc etc.

Comment: Have you set the tabsHideOnSubPages attribute value for any bottom tabs configuration?

Comment: @PradnyaSinalkar yeah i have :( Also read that tabsHideOnSubPages:false is the default value but i still have it :(